# How to count number of vertices in a particular graph.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, path-connected

Let $4\leq r\leq \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ and $P_n$ be a path graph on $n\geq 2r$ vertices.

$V(P_n) = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$.

We obtain a graph $H$ by adding a vertex $x$ to $P_n$ such that $x$ is adjacent to vertices $v_l$ and $v_m$
such that $d(v_1,v_n) = r+1$, where $l<m$, $l\neq 1$ and $m\neq n$. $P_n$ induced graph in $H$.
For other vertices in $H$, Eccentricity is $r$. 
Obviously, $v_2,\ldots,v_{l-1},v_{m+1},v_{n-1}$ can not be adjacent to $x$ otherwise $d(v_1,v_n) \neq r+1$

Also, vertices $x,v_l,v_{l+1},\ldots,v_m$ form a cycle $C : x,v_l,v_{l+1},\ldots,v_m,x$.

I need to show that by proposed construction Eccentricity of $x$ will not be $r$ if every or some vertices from the set $\{v_{l+1},\ldots,v_{m-1}\}$ are adjacent to $x$.

I felt I need to show that this cycle $C$ is of length less than $2r$. 
By taking particular values it is coming true but I am unable to prove it. 
And then distance between $x$ to $v_1$ or $v_n$ must be less than or greater than $r$ to prove the contradiction. 
Kindly help. Thanks for your timely help and guidance.

**P.S.** I tried to count the number of vertices from $v_l$ up to $v_m$ and it turned out to be
$(m-l +1)$ number of vertices. But I am unable to proceed from here. How to show that $C$ contains less than $2r$ vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is given in three parts. In the first, we will come to the conclusion that $r \le 5$ must hold, which (together with restrictions in the problem) means only $r=4$ and $r=5$ are at all possible.

As next step, the case $r=5$ is handled. The conditions are used to more and more clarify the structure of a potential graph $H$ that fullfills the conditions, until only one graph remains. It is then shown that this graph contains a vertex with eccentricity > $r$, so no such graph $H$ actually exists.

Finally, $r=4$ is considered. The conditions can be used similar as in $r=5$, with a bit more leeway needing a few more steps. But again, it can be shown that any such graph must contain a vertex with eccentricity > $r$.

---

The 'new' vertex $x$ in $H$ allows a potential shortcut from $v_1$ to $v_n$ between $v_l$ and $v_m$ via $x$. So the length (number of edges) of the path $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_l, x, v_m, v_{m+1},\ldots,v_n$ is

- $l-1$ from $v_1$ to $v_l$,
- $2$ for the $v_l,x,v_m$ part, and
- $n-m$ from $v_m$ to $v_n$.

That makes the overall length of the path (which is equal to the distance of $v_1$ and $v_n$ in graph $H$, if we choose $m > l+1$) equal to $(l-1)+2+(n-m)=n+l-m+1$. With the assumption that

$$d(v_1,v_n)=n+l-m+1=r+1$$

we get $r=n+l-m$, or equivalently

$$m-l = n-r \tag{1}\label{eq1}.$$

From the problem statement we know that there might be more edges of the type $(x,v_i)$, with $l+1\le i \le m-1$.

We know that $x$ has eccentricity $r$ in $H$, so there is an index $k$ with $1\le k \le n$ with $d(x,v_k)=r$ and $d(x,v_i)\le r,\, \forall i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Let's assume $k \le l$. Then obviously $d(x,v_k)=1+(l-k)$ (1 step from $x$ to $v_l$, then $l-k$ steps to $v_k$). In addition, $d(x,v_1) > d(x,v_i), \forall i=2,3,\ldots,l$, so we must have $k=1$ and hence $r=d(x,v_1)=l$.

Considering $\eqref{eq1}$ this implies the forbidden equality $m=n$. So we cannot have $v_k$ lie on the part of the graph that connects the first vertex $v_1$ to the cycle C=$(x,v_l,v_{l+1},\ldots,v_m,x)$.

In absolutely the same way one can show that $k \ge m$ implies first $k=n$, then $r=n-m+1$, which implies with $\eqref{eq1}$ that $l=1$, which is forbidden.

Both parts together mean that $l+1 \le k \le m-1$, or that $v_k$ lies on the cycle $C$ itself.

What's the distance of $v_l$ to $v_k$? It cannot be less then $r-1$. If it was less, we could prepend the edge from $x$ to $v_l$ to the path that realizes that small distance from $v_l$ to $v_k$, and get a path from $x$ to $v_k$ of length less than $r$, which is impossible. So we get

$$d(v_l,v_k) \ge r-1. \tag{2} \label{eq2}$$

Now we can show that $l$ must be less than $4$. If it was not, and we had $l\ge 4$, let's consider the distance from $v_2$ to $v_k$. Any path from $v_2$ to $v_k$ must necessarily pass through $v_l$. The part of the path from $v_2$ to $v_l$ has exactly $l-2$ edges, and the part from $v_l$ to $v_k$ has at least (see $\eqref{eq2}$) $r-1$ edges.

That means, taking into account that we assumed $l\ge 4$:

$$d(v_2,v_k) \ge (l-2)+(r-1) \ge 2+(r-1)=r+1,$$

which means that the eccentricity of $v_2$ is bigger than $r$, which is impossible, so we know that

$$l \le 3. \tag{3} \label{eq3}$$

Again one can make the same argument for the 'other end' of the original path $P_n$. We get

$$d(v_m,v_k) \ge r-1, \tag{4} \label{eq4}$$

in analgoy to $\eqref{eq2}$ and the assumption $n-m > 2$ leads to the impossible $d(v_{n-1},v_k) \ge r+1$. So we get the analogous inequality

$$n-m \le 2.\tag{5} \label{eq5}$$

From $\eqref{eq3}$ we get $m-l \ge m-3$ and from $\eqref{eq5}$ follows $m \ge n-2$, which combined means $m-l \ge n-5$. If we now look back at $\eqref{eq1}$, we find $n-r \ge n-5$, or equivalently $r\le 5$.

---

Let's consider the case $r=5$. That means both inequalities $\eqref{eq3}$ and $\eqref{eq5}$ must actually be sharp (equalities), so we have

$$l=3, m=n-2.$$

In addition both $\eqref{eq2}$ and $\eqref{eq4}$ must be sharp as well (otherwise we had $d(v_2,v_k)>r$ or $d(v_{n-1},v_k)>r$, resp):

$$d(v_l,v_k)=r-1=d(v_m,v_k)$$

No path of minimal length from $v_l$ to $v_k$ can go through $x$ (because if it would, we'd have an even shorter path from $x$ to $v_k$, which is impossible). That means such a minimal path can only exist in the original $P_n$ graph, which means that minimal path is simply $v_l,v_{l+1},\ldots,v_k$.

Considering that $r=5,l=3$ and $d(v_l,v_k)=r-1=4$, we get $k=7$. Note that no edge from $x$ to any of the nodes $v_4,v_5,v_6$ and $v_7$ may exist. If it would, we'd have $d(x,v_k)<r$, as assuming for example that edge $(x,v_4)$ exists, $x,v_4,v_5,v_6,v_7$ would be a path of lenght $4$ from $x$ to $v_k$.

Similiarly, no minimal path from $v_m$ to $v_k$ can pass through $x$, so whe have that the path $v_m,v_{m-1},\ldots,v_k$ has lenght $4$ and thus we get $m=11$ and $n=13$. Again, no edge from $x$ to any of $v_8,v_9,v_{10}$ may exist, as it would create a path from $x$ to $v_k=v_7$ that is shorter than $5$.

Summing this all up: For $r=5$ the only possibly graph is an $H$ with $n=13, l=3, m=11$ and no other edge from $x$ to any of the $v_i$, other than to $v_3$ and $v_{11}$ exists. This is just one graph, no variation possible.

It's easy to see that $d(v_6,v_{11})=5$ (both ways around the cycle $C$ have that length), and hence $d(v_6,v_{12})=6$, which contradicts the eccentricity condition.

---

Let's consider the remaining case $r=4$. The inequalities $\eqref{eq3}$ and $\eqref{eq5}$ cannot both be strict. If we had both $l \le 2$ and $m \ge n-1$ we'd get the impossible $r \le 3$, just as we did above when we proved $r\le 5$.

Let's assume w.l.o.g, that we have $l=3$ (the other case is totally symmetrical). Then we can have

1. $m=n-2$ (as in the case $r=5$), or
2. $m=n-1$

Since $m \ge n-2$ and $m\neq n$, no other cases are possible.

Case 1 is handled exactly as for $r=5$. It can be proved exactly the same way that both $\eqref{eq2}$ and $\eqref{eq4}$ must be sharp. The only difference is that since $r=4$, we get $k=6$, then $m=9$ and $n=11$. Again one proves that $d(v_5,v_9)=4$ and $d(v_5,v_{10})=5>r$, which is a contradiction.

Let's consider case 2. Again $\eqref{eq2}$ must be sharp, with the same argument as before. As a side note, that argument doesn't work any more for $\eqref{eq4}$, because $v_{n-1}$ and $v_m$ are now one and the same vertex, in all previous cases they were different.

But with $\eqref{eq2}$ sharp, we can again conclude that the minimal length path from $v_2$ to $v_k$ must be $v_2,v_3,v_4,\ldots,v_k$ and hence we get $k=6$ and no edges from $x$ to $v_4,v_5$ or $v_6$ exist!

Since the path $x,v_{n-1},v_{n-2},\ldots,v_k$ cannot be shorter than length $4$, we have that the part from $v_{n-1}$ to $v_k$ cannot be shorter than length $3$, so we get $(n-1) - 6 \ge 3$, or $n\ge 10$. Again, no edge from $x$ to $v_7$ or $v_8$ may exist, as this shortens the distance from $x$ to $v_k=v_6$ below $4$.

That means any path from $v_5$ to $v_{n-1}$ has length at least 4. If one starts the path by going to $v_4$, the only option to continue is $v_3$, then $x$, then $v_{n-1}$ (length = $4$). If one starts the path in the other direction ($v_6$), one has again no other option than to go to $v_7,v_8$ and $v_9$ next. Since $n\ge 10$, that means after 4 steps we just arrived at $v_{n-1}$ (or even not yet, if $n > 10$).

So we have $d(v_5,v_{n-1}) \ge 4$ and hence $d(v_5,v_n) \ge 5$, which is against the eccentricity condition on $v_5$.

This concludes the proof!

Comment: @Dear Ingix, I have updated the question.

Comment: Yeah exactly what I need to prove. That there is no such graph and hence a contradiction. I just need one point considering eccentricity of $x$ to prove the non-existence of such a graph.

Comment: Yeah that is my point. I am trying to construct such a graph $H$ from $P_n$ by adding one single vertex $x$. I have to show that this is not possible and hence we need at least two vertices to be added to $P_n$ to construct such graph $H$.I am trying to prove by contradiction. That by such construction eccentricity of $x$ is not $r$.

Comment: @monalisa A good small upper bound for $r$ is now proven. Maybe you can take it from here? I will, time permitting, try to add a complete solution.

Comment: Yeah sure. Even I am just going through your answer :) Trying to understand .. Thanks a lot

Comment: @monalisa Proof is complete now, feel free to ask if anything is unclear!

Comment: By proving the condition that $r\leq5$ in your proof, you mean to say that in my original question I must put $r\geq 6$ to get the contradiction that $r\leq 5$? Am I right? I understood up to equation $(3)$ but I could not get the part after this. I mean I got the lines proved by you after (3) but what is the use? I mean how it is useful to contradict that e(x) won't be $r$. Or you want to say that If I put original conditions as $6\leq r\leq \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ then we get a contradiction as we get $r\leq5$ in the end? Did I get it right?

Comment: Maybe we still misunderstand each other.  You start with $r,n$ given with the stated conditions (icnluding $r \ge 4$). Then you take the path $P_n$. Then you add one additional vertex $x$ and add edges from $x$ to $v_l$ and $v_m$ with the given conditions: $1 < l < m < n$. You can (but are not required to) add more edges from $x$ to any vertex $v_i, l < i < m$. This gives you the graph $H$. You have the additional requirements that $ d(v_1,v_n)=r+1$ and that the eccentricity of each vertex in $H$ (besides $v_v,v_n$) is $r$. The task is to prove that this is impossible.

Comment: I think it's best if you draw the graph $H$, it's a path from $v_1$ to $v_l$, then comes the cycle $C$, then again a path from $v_m$ to $v_n$. This should hopefully make the arguments clearer. 

Like any proof by contradiction, my proof is talking and proving things about a graph $H$ that ultimately does not exist. Proving $r \le 5$ first means that I do not need to worry about any scenario whith $r > 5$ anymore. It's like considering cases: 1) $r=4$, 2)$r=5$, 3) $r > 5$. It just so happens that I did part 3) first, then 2), then 1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95458/discussion-between-monalisa-and-ingix).